# How to select first sentence in a piece of text using regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My task is to select first sentence from a text (I'm writing in `C#`). I suppose that the most appropriate way would be using `regex` but some troubles occurred. What regex pattern should I use to select the first sentence?

Several examples:

1. Input: "I am a lion and I want to be free. Do you see a lion when you look inside of me?" Expected result: "I am a lion and I want to be free."
2. Input: "I drink so much they call me Charlie 4.0 hands. Any text." Expected result: "I drink so much they call me Charlie 4.0 hands."
3. Input: "So take out your hands and throw the H.U. up. 'Now wave it around like you don't give a fake!'" Expected result: "So take out your hands and throw the H.U. up."

The third is really confusing me.

Comment: What regex pattern have you tried until now?

Comment: What if senteces are "glued"? Like `I am a lion and I want to be free.Do you see a lion when you look inside of me?` I can provide a regex for the current sentences, but again, what about `Some sentence. iPad ....`?

Comment: I doubt there is a foolproof way to do it across the entirety of legitimate english sentences.  You can pretty easily write a little logic that will be right 99% of the time though.

Comment: There must be some hidden logic for dots inside the sentence - like "dot inside sentence may be used only after number or capital letter". Is it so? If yes, than anyone here can provide the regex... but HubertL has good point - what regexes have you tried until now (i.e. you should solve your home work by yourself ;-))

Comment: Figure out the rules in English, then try to translate them to Regex, and ask if you need help.

Comment: It is assumed that sentences are divided by a whitespace.

Comment: "blah blah throw the H.U. up." <- how do you stop this dividing into two sentences: `blah blah throw the H.U.` and `up.` ?

Comment: I have come up with 2 suggestions: [`^(?:[\p{Lu}\d]\.|[^.?!])*[.?!]`](http://regexstorm.net/Tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5b%5cp%7bLu%7d%5cd%5d%5c.%7c%5b%5e.%3f!%5d)*%5b.%3f!%5d&i=So+take+out+your+hands+and+throw+the+H.U.+up.+%27Now+wave+it+around+like+you+don%27t+give+a+fake!) and  [`^\p{Lu}.*?[.?!](?=\s+(?:$|\p{P}*\p{Lu}))`](http://regexstorm.net/Tester?p=%5e%5cp%7bLu%7d.*%3f%5b.%3f!%5d(%3f%3d%5cs%2b(%3f%3a%24%7c%5cp%7bP%7d*%5cp%7bLu%7d))&i=So+take+out+your+hands+and+throw+the+H.U.+up.+%27Now+wave+it+around+like+you+don%27t+give+a+fake!%27). No idea if they will work for all of your data.

Comment: HubertL, from latest: "\. [^[a-z]]". And variants with different options for '[]', etc.

Comment: Regex is overkill for this task.  Split the string on ". " and take the first element in the resulting array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you aleready provided some assumptions:

> sentences are divided by a whitespace
>   task is to select first sentence

You can use the following regex:

```
^.*?[.?!](?=\s+(?:$|\p{P}*\p{Lu}))
```

See [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/Tester?p=%5E.*%3F%5B.%3F!%5D(%3F%3D%5Cs%2B(%3F%3A%24%7C%5Cp%7BP%7D*%5Cp%7BLu%7D))&i=So%20take%20out%20your%20hands%20and%20throw%20the%20H.U.%20up.%20%27Now%20wave%20it%20around%20like%20you%20don%27t%20give%20a%20fake!%27)

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string (thus, only the first sentence will be matched)
- `.*?` - any number of characters, as few as possible (use `RegexOptions.Singleline` to also match a newline with `.`)
- `[.?!]` - a final punctuation symbol
- `(?=\s+(?:$|\p{P}*\p{Lu}))` - a look-ahead making sure there is 1 or more whitespace symbols (`\s+`) right after before the end of string (`$`) or optional punctuation (`\p{P}`) and a capital letter (`\p{Lu}`).

**UPDATE**:

Since it turns out you can have single sentence input, and your sentences can start with any letter or digit, you can use

```
^.*?[.?!](?=\s+\p{P}*[\p{Lu}\p{N}]|\s*$)
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/Tester?p=%5E.*%3F%5B.%3F!%5D(%3F%3D%5Cs%2B%5Cp%7BP%7D*%5B%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%5D%7C%5Cs*%24)&i=So%20take%20out%20your%20hands%20and%20throw%20the%20H.U.%20up.)

Comment: I hope that it will be at least helpful.

Comment: Excellent answer, though it doesn't match when there's only 1 sentence in the text (with no trailing whitespaces). It could be solved with `^.*?[.?!](?=\s+\p{P}*\p{Lu}|\s*$)`

Comment: Actually, I thought there was another assumption: there must be at least two sentences in the input.

Comment: This is really close to what I need. My final solution is: "^.*?[.?!](?=\s+\p{P}*(\p{Lu}|\d)|\s*$)". Because sentences can start with digit.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a regular expression that uses lots of negative look-aheads to exclude certain cases, e.g. a punctuation must *not* be followed by lowercase character, or a dot before a capital letter is not closing a sentence. This splits up all the text in their seperate sentences. If you are given a text, just take the first match.

`[\s\S]*?(?![A-Z]+)(?:\.|\?|\!)(?!(?:\d|[A-Z]))(?! [a-z])/gm`

[image: regex]

Comment: This is a C# related question, not JavaScript. And you need to learn more about character classes to write more optimal patterns. `(?:\d|[A-Z])` or `(?:\.|\?|\!)` are not effecient compared to `[\dA-Z]` and `[?!.]`.

Answer (score -1):

Sentence separators should be searched with following scanner:

- if it's `sentence-finisher` character (like [.!?])

  - it must be followed by space or allowed sequence of characters and then space:

    - like sequence of '.' for '.' (`A sentence...`)
    - ...or sequence of '!' and/or '?' for '!' and '?' (`Exclamation here!?`)
  - then it must be followed by either:

    - capital character (ignore quotes, if any)
    - numeric

      - which *must* be followed by lowercase or another `sentence-finister`
    - `dialog-starter` character (`Blah blah blah... - And what next, Elric?`)

*Tip: don't forget to add extra space character to input source string.*

**Upd:**

Some wild pseudocode xD:

```
func sentence(inputString) {
    finishers = ['.', '!', '?']

    allowedSequences = ['.' => ['..'], '!' => ['!!', '?'], '?' => ['??', '!']]

    input = inputString
    result = ''

    found = false
    while input != '' {

        finisherPos = min(pos(input, finishers))

        if !finisherPos
            return inputString

        result += substr(input, 0, finisherPos + 1)
        input = substr(input, finisherPos)

        p = finisherPos

            finisher = input[p]

            p++

            if input[p] != ' '
                if match = testSequence(substr(input, p), allowedSequences[finisher]) {
                    result += match
                    found = true
                    break
                } else {
                    continue
                }
            else {
                p++
                if input[p] in [A-Z] {
                    found = true
                    break
                }

                if input[p] in [0-9] {
                    p++
                    if input[p] in [a-z] or input[p] in finishers {
                        found = true
                        break
                    }
                    p--
                }

                if input[p] in ['-'] {
                    found = true;
                    break
                }
            }

    }

    if !found 
        return inputStr

    return result
}

func testSequence(str, sequences) {
    foreach (sequence: sequences)
        if startsWith(str, sequence)
            return sequence

    return false
}
```